# The type 'System.Uri' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.What is this error?

Tags: mvvmcross, portable-class-library

This question may already have an answer here:
I am creating MvvmCross PCL library using Visual Studio 2013 ultimate on my windows 8 machine.

And My PCL target frameworks are -

- Net framework 4.52 and higher
- W 8
- xamarin Andoid
- xamarin iOs

I am getting following error
**The type 'System.Uri' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.**

I am creating PCL using MvvmCross.One method in my FirstViewModel class is as follows.

```
    public async Task<object> GetConstituencyByUserId(string userId)
    {
        try
        {
              HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
              string url ="";
              HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.GetAsync(url);
              if (response.ReasonPhrase.Contains("OK"))
              {
                 if (response != null)
                 {
                     var jsonSerializer = 
                     new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(constituency));
                     var stream = await     response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                     return (constituency)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(stream);
                 }

              }
              else if (response.ReasonPhrase.Contains("Bad Request"))
              {
                 return null;
              }
              else
              {
                  return null;
              }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
                          // App.errorlog.WriteToLog(ex.Message);
         }
        return null;
    }
```

And It is pointing to line of HttpResponseMessage. and giving above error.

Anyone knows ?

Comment: Please edit this question to provide more information - are you compiling using Xamarin Studio or VisualStudio? which client platform are you targetting - WindowPhone, WindowsStore, Android and/or iOS? which profile is the PCL? Are you referencing HttpClient via the Micosoft nuget packages? The better information you supply, the easier it will be for others to answer.

Comment: There is an example of using HttpClient in MvvmCross - including source code and video - in http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/quick-run-through-using-pcls-in.html

Comment: @Stuart Sir,I have edited my question